# Avoiding to loop a pandas series; Subsetting on dynamically changed arguments

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, series

I know it's best to avoid looping/iterating over a pandas series. However, for my use case I can't find an appropriate solution.

I have an integer series like (100,101,103,102,99,100,102) etc. and I would like to find the entries/index whenever the value has moved up by e.g. 3. For the above mini series that would be the indexvalues (2,6).

System info: Python Version: 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 21:57:25)[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)], Pandas version: '0.17.1'

Here is my code, including a sample series

```
import pandas as pd


def getMoves(t: pd.Series, triggervar = 3):
    # t is a series of integer values
    # iterate a given series and collect all movements that are equal or greater than 3
    triggerindexes= []

    currentreference = t[0]
    trigger = t[0] + triggervar

    for item in t.iteritems():
        print(item)
        if item[1] >= trigger:
            triggerindexes.append(item[0])
            currentreference = item[1]
            trigger = item[1] + triggervar
            print('--- New move triggered :' + str(item))
        elif item[1] < currentreference:
            currentreference = item[1]
            trigger = item[1] + triggervar
            print('--- Set trigger, as current value lower than refvalue, new refvalue: ' + str(item[1]))

    return triggerindexes



#create a sample time series
ts = pd.read_json('{"1457427600000":100,"1457427615000":100,"1457427630000":101,"1457427645000":100,"1457427660000":100,"1457427675000":101,"1457427690000":101,"1457427705000":101,"1457427720000":100,"1457427735000":99,"1457427750000":98,"1457427765000":97,"1457427780000":96,"1457427795000":97,"1457427810000":98,"1457427825000":97,"1457427840000":98,"1457427855000":97,"1457427870000":98,"1457427885000":98,"1457427900000":97,"1457427915000":97,"1457427930000":96,"1457427945000":97,"1457427960000":96,"1457427975000":97,"1457427990000":96,"1457428005000":96,"1457428020000":95,"1457428035000":96,"1457428050000":95,"1457428065000":94,"1457428080000":94,"1457428095000":95,"1457428110000":96,"1457428125000":97,"1457428140000":97,"1457428155000":97,"1457428170000":97,"1457428185000":97,"1457428200000":98,"1457428215000":98,"1457428230000":99,"1457428245000":99,"1457428260000":99,"1457428275000":98,"1457428290000":97,"1457428305000":96,"1457428320000":96,"1457428335000":96,"1457428350000":96,"1457428365000":97,"1457428380000":97,"1457428395000":98,"1457428410000":99,"1457428425000":100,"1457428440000":101,"1457428455000":102,"1457428470000":101,"1457428485000":101,"1457428500000":102,"1457428515000":102,"1457428530000":103,"1457428545000":103,"1457428560000":102,"1457428575000":102,"1457428590000":101,"1457428605000":102,"1457428620000":102,"1457428635000":103,"1457428650000":102,"1457428665000":103,"1457428680000":103,"1457428695000":104,"1457428710000":104,"1457428725000":104,"1457428740000":105,"1457428755000":104,"1457428770000":103,"1457428785000":104,"1457428800000":104,"1457428815000":104,"1457428830000":104,"1457428845000":103,"1457428860000":102,"1457428875000":101,"1457428890000":102,"1457428905000":102,"1457428920000":101,"1457428935000":101,"1457428950000":102,"1457428965000":103,"1457428980000":102,"1457428995000":101,"1457429010000":102,"1457429025000":102,"1457429040000":102,"1457429055000":102,"1457429070000":101,"1457429085000":101,"1457429100000":102,"1457429115000":101,"1457429130000":101,"1457429145000":102,"1457429160000":102,"1457429175000":101,"1457429190000":100,"1457429205000":100,"1457429220000":101,"1457429235000":100,"1457429250000":101,"1457429265000":100,"1457429280000":99,"1457429295000":100,"1457429310000":99,"1457429325000":100,"1457429340000":100,"1457429355000":99,"1457429370000":98,"1457429385000":98,"1457429400000":97,"1457429415000":97,"1457429430000":96,"1457429445000":95,"1457429460000":96,"1457429475000":97,"1457429490000":98,"1457429505000":99,"1457429520000":98,"1457429535000":97,"1457429550000":98,"1457429565000":97,"1457429580000":96,"1457429595000":95,"1457429610000":94,"1457429625000":93,"1457429640000":94,"1457429655000":95,"1457429670000":94,"1457429685000":95,"1457429700000":94,"1457429715000":94,"1457429730000":95,"1457429745000":95,"1457429760000":94,"1457429775000":93,"1457429790000":94,"1457429805000":93,"1457429820000":92,"1457429835000":91,"1457429850000":92,"1457429865000":93,"1457429880000":93,"1457429895000":92,"1457429910000":92,"1457429925000":91,"1457429940000":90,"1457429955000":89,"1457429970000":90,"1457429985000":89,"1457430000000":88,"1457430015000":88,"1457430030000":89,"1457430045000":89,"1457430060000":90,"1457430075000":90,"1457430090000":90,"1457430105000":90,"1457430120000":91,"1457430135000":90,"1457430150000":91,"1457430165000":91,"1457430180000":91,"1457430195000":92,"1457430210000":92,"1457430225000":91,"1457430240000":91,"1457430255000":92,"1457430270000":93,"1457430285000":92,"1457430300000":93,"1457430315000":94,"1457430330000":93,"1457430345000":94,"1457430360000":95,"1457430375000":94,"1457430390000":95,"1457430405000":94,"1457430420000":94,"1457430435000":93,"1457430450000":93,"1457430465000":94,"1457430480000":94,"1457430495000":93,"1457430510000":94,"1457430525000":95,"1457430540000":94,"1457430555000":93,"1457430570000":93,"1457430585000":92,"1457430600000":91,"1457430615000":90,"1457430630000":90,"1457430645000":89,"1457430660000":88,"1457430675000":87,"1457430690000":86,"1457430705000":85,"1457430720000":85,"1457430735000":85,"1457430750000":85,"1457430765000":86,"1457430780000":85,"1457430795000":85,"1457430810000":84,"1457430825000":83,"1457430840000":84,"1457430855000":85,"1457430870000":85,"1457430885000":84,"1457430900000":84,"1457430915000":83,"1457430930000":83,"1457430945000":84,"1457430960000":83,"1457430975000":84,"1457430990000":85,"1457431005000":86,"1457431020000":87,"1457431035000":86,"1457431050000":86,"1457431065000":85,"1457431080000":84,"1457431095000":84,"1457431110000":84,"1457431125000":83,"1457431140000":82,"1457431155000":83,"1457431170000":82,"1457431185000":81}', typ='series', orient='records')

#get up-moves by 3; resulting in 9 hits
results=getMoves(ts)
```

Well, it works, but as my real world problem has lots of records (>2.5 billion) it's a very slow approach. I tried some things by applying a function by apply, but as the reference value is set dynamically I could not find a working solution. I also tried to look into the pipe functionality but it has left me quite confused.

So if anybody has some hints to avoid the exhaustive looping I would be very happy and thankful. It's my first question here, as I am still a newbie and I do hope I have formulated my question well.

Answer (score 0):

it's an update as I found a good solution.

I enhanced the speed significantly by using the numba library. Sorry for posting this as an answer, but I cannot find my edit button:(

Enhancement is

%timeit getMoves_numba(series)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.72 ms per loop

compared to pure Python

%timeit getMoves(series)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.87 s per loop

The sample series I have created has 5 million records. The function getMoves now returns a boolean index array for further use... For my purpose the 10ms is sufficient. With just one declaration being getMoves_numba = nb.autojit(getMoves)... nice:)

Here is my new code:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb




def getMoves(v:np.array,points:int = 3, up:bool=True):
    J=len(v)
    refvalue=np.int
    bound=np.int
    result= np.zeros((J), dtype=bool)
    if up == True:
        refvalue=v[0]
        bound=refvalue+points
        for j in range(J):
            if v[j] >= bound:
                result[j]=True
                refvalue = v[j]
                bound=refvalue+points
            elif v[j] < refvalue:
                refvalue = v[j]
                bound=refvalue+points                
    else:
        refvalue=v[0]
        bound=refvalue-points
        for j in range(J):
            if v[j] <= bound:
                result[j]=True
                refvalue = v[j]
                bound=refvalue-points
            elif v[j] > refvalue:
                refvalue = v[j]
                bound=refvalue-points
    return result

np.random.seed(257931)
N=5000000
series=np.random.random_integers(-1,1,size=N)
series[0]=100
series=series.cumsum()
series = series + (abs(series.min())+1)

getMoves_numba = nb.autojit(getMoves)
```

This is done on a pure numpy array, so if being used while working with a pandas series I have to pass it on by pandas.series.values.

Improvement is good, but if you have a hint or comment regarding style, I still appreciate some feedback.

Regards

C